# How is the rating calculated in Wordfeud?

Tags: wordfeud

Winning a game increases your rating by a certain number, and losing decreases your rating by a certain number. I've gotten anything between 6-20, possibly more.

This is independent from the game score, which is explained in the manual. How exactly is the rating calculated?